# read line from file and store each word into an array (C language)

Tags: c, arrays, file, strtok

I'm trying to make a function in C that reads a first line form file and store each word into an array of strings, than return the array or print it (I used strtok()). I've written my code but when I test it I get an error: "segmentation error" which I don't know what it means.
any help??? I saw this question [Segmentation fault with array of strings C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236542/segmentation-fault-with-array-of-strings-c)
i think it's similar but I still don't understand.
Here's my code :

**the function that reads data from file and store it into an array** 
function is on the file: methodes.c

```
void lireFichier (char *file)
{
    int i = 0;
    int nbElement = 4;
    char ** tab;
    char line [1000];
    char *str[1000];
    const char s[2] = " ";
    char *token;
    FILE *myFile;

    myFile = fopen(file, "r");
    if(!myFile)
    {
        printf("could not open file");
    } else
    {
        printf("file opened\n");
        //while(fgets(line,sizeof line,myFile)!= NULL) 

        //get the fisrt line 
        fgets(line,sizeof line,myFile);

        //fprintf(stdout,"%s",line); 
        //get the fisrt word
        token = strtok(line, s);

        for(i =0; (i< nbElement) && (token != NULL); i++)
        {
            int len = strlen(token); 
            tab[i] = malloc(len);
            strncpy(tab[i], token, len-1);
            token = strtok(NULL, s);
            //printf( "%s\n", tab[i]);
        }   
    }
    fclose(myFile);
}
```

**and here's the main.c** 
// I pass the file as argument (in argv)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "methodes.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int result = 1;
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Erreur dans les arguments\n");
    } else
    {
        int idx;
        for (idx = 0; idx < argc; idx++)
        {
            printf("parameter %d value is %s\n", idx, argv[idx]);
        }

       lireFichier(argv[1]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**and here's an example of the file : methodes.txt**

```
afficher tableau
partager elements roles
nommer type profession
fin
```

**and this is my output:**

```
file opened
Erreur de segmentation
```

**note:** the output is in french, so the message means segmentation error 
thank you and sorry for all the details, i just wanted to make sure that people understand what i mean.

Comment: `tab` is not initialize (not allocated memory) and used `tab[i]`, So occurs segmentation fault.

Comment: also `tab[i] = malloc(len);strncpy(tab[i], token, len-1);token = strtok(NULL, s);` --> `tab[i] = malloc(len+1); strcpy(tab[i], token);token = strtok(NULL, " \n");`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I changed the initialization of the array like this: char *tab[4], and the code works fine. but when I tried what u said in the 2nd comment it gives me a compilation error: too few arguments to function \u2018strncpy\u2019   strncpy(tab[i], token);

Comment: u have typo `strncpy` as `strcpy`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes, sorry. If I could ask u another question... I want my function to returns me an array of strings then use it in the main; I did this : char ** lireFichier(char *line) {....}  and in the main : char *tab[4];  tab = lireFichier(line);    (I changed the parameters , Ipasse a string to the function instead of a file )  but this doesn't work ..

Comment: `char **tab = malloc(nbElement * sizeof(char*));` or `char **tab = malloc(nbElement * sizeof(*tab));` .. `return tab;`. at main `char **tab = lireFichier(argv[1]);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank u again :), do I need to allocate memory for every string of the array in the main?, cause I keep getting that segmentation arror after the result is well printed .. char **tab = lireFichier(line);
for(i = 0; i<nbElement; i++){printf("%s\n", tab[i]);}

Comment: `afficher tableau` has two elements and `malloc` return  uninitialize memory block. a way ..   `char **tab = calloc(nbElement, sizeof(char*));` at main `for(i = 0; i<nbElement && tab[i]; i++){printf("%s\n", tab[i]);}`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank u :D , u're awesome, u helped me a lot, it works I can now continue the rest of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 char ** tab;
```

Is a uninitialised pointer to a pointer. What you need is a array of pointers.

```
char *tab[10];
```

Instead of 10, use the size you see fit and adjust your code to include bounds checking.

Comment: Thank u so much guys for answering, now I understand my error, I just changed how I initialized the array : char *tab[4]; and everything works fine, it was that simple and but didn't pay attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_array_of_pointers.htm

pointer of an array:

```
int *ptr[MAX];
```